# IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio SQL Adapter User Password in Encrypted format

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I'm Using IBM SQLAdapter for storing updating user information.. but I want to store password in database in encrypted format. and displaying password shown in decrepted format.. how can i do this using IBM MobileFirst Stdio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will read the error message, you'll see it's not related to your installed Java version nor to the Eclipse version you're using.

I've tried myself on Mac OS X 10.10.1 and Eclipse Kepler SR2. The installation from the Marketplace was successful. Note that the installed artifacts are the same whether you use Windows, Linux or Mac.

It was very slow, though, so it could be it something 'bad' happened during it.
This may also be due to either a network problem or temporary cache problem on the servers.

What you can do:

- Wait and try again later,
- Or download [this Studio .zip file](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_studio_plugin_6.3.0.0.zip). Then, in Eclipse > Help > Install new software... > Add > Archive, and select the downloaded .zip file.

Comment: thanks Adar.. I downloaded Zip file and installed using eclipse.. its working..thanks..iam trying past 3 days through eclipse market place..